# The Derivative of Function within a Function

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm trying to prove that the equation

$$u_t = p(u)\,u_x, \,\,\,\,\, t>0$$

has a solution satisfying

$$u = f(x + p(u)t)$$

where p is real.

My understanding is that one should first seek $u_t$ and $u_x$.

Having consulted my notes

$$u_t = f'(x+p(u)t) \,(p(u) + p'(u)u_t\,t)$$
$$u_x = f'(x+p(u)t)\,(1+p'(u)u_x\,t)$$

However, I do not understand how to arrive at these derivatives of $u$. If, say, we re-write the expression above as

$$u = f(g)$$

would

$$u_t = u_g \times u_t\,?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are merely instances of the chain rule.  For instance, $$u_t = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x + p(u)t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x+p(u)t) \cdot f'(x+p(u)t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(p(u)t) \cdot f'(x+p(u)t),$$ and this final derivative would be computed using the product and chain rules together: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(p(u)t) = u_t \cdot p'(u) t + p(u)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain how you got the $u_t $ term when evaluating $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(p(u)t)$?

Comment: Yes: $u$ is a function of $t$ and is inside of the function $p$. Thus, by the chain rule, we should have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(u) = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} u \right) \cdot p’(u) = u_t \cdot p’(u)$$